# How to hide firefox lower left message box?

Tags: firefox, user-interface

In desktop Firefox whenever I hover a url the browser shows the corresponding url in the lower left corner. Also, when a website is being downloaded this message box in the lower left corner shows the url. Finally, it sometimes says "Timed Out".
How do I completely disable this box?

This is a similar question https://support.mozilla.org/lt/questions/1372339 , but I don't think such an annoying and useless piece of UI can't be disabled easier.

Comment: It's so you can see that a link is going to the place it purports to & not some random hacker site.

Comment: @Tetsujin, yes, you are correct. However on a website with movies it says "Timed Out". Everything works, but this pop up is being shown even in a full screen mode. Obviously it is absolutely useless and I'm surprised FF fell so low given how good their product is otherwise. Since this is a rare case, I used a more frequent one (url addresses) to explain which pop up I'd like to get rid of.

Comment: This box is essential for knowing what's going on. It's one of the most important tools in FF.

Comment: @harrymc, I appreciate your advice. This box might even be useful in the majority of cases. However do I really need to see the message "Timed Out" while I watch a movie in FF?

Comment: Yes, it tells you that playing has failed because of a network problem. Otherwise, you just wait for playing to resume until your patience runs out.

Comment: @harrymc, except that playing works perfectly. Like I said above, everything works and I was watching a movie. The content of the box is useless and wrong, and also the box itself is the problem that was preventing me from enjoying the movie. Thankfully I managed to piece together a piece of custom css and remove this mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed instruction from here: https://support.mozilla.org/lt/questions/1372339 . Here it is for reference.

> 1. Open Firefox;
> 2. Type in about:config in the address bar;
> 3. In the about:config page, search toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets
> 4. Enable it by double-clicking it;
> 5. Open a New Tab and close the about:config
> 6. Click the Application Menu(three-lines icon);
> 7. Click Help;
> 8. Click More troubleshooting information
> 9. On the page that appeared, scroll down and click the button that says Open Directory;
> 10. File Explorer will automatically open, find a folder named `chrome` in there;
> 11. If there's no `chrome` folder, make a new folder there and name it `chrome`;
> 12. Open that `chrome` folder;
> 13. Right-click and select New, click Text Document;
> 14. Name the document userChrome.css;
> 15. Double-click that file, it should open a text editor (such as Notepad);
> 16. Copy the following:
>
> ```
> #statuspanel[type="overLink"] #statuspanel-label
> #statuspanel[type="status"] #statuspanel-label[value^="Look"],
> #statuspanel[type="status"] #statuspanel-label[value^="Connect"],
> #statuspanel[type="status"] #statuspanel-label[value^="Send"],
> #statuspanel[type="status"] #statuspanel-label[value^="Transfer"],
> #statuspanel[type="status"] #statuspanel-label[value^="Read"],
> #statuspanel[type="status"] #statuspanel-label[value^="Wrote"],
> #statuspanel[type="status"] #statuspanel-label[value^="Wait"],
> #statuspanel[type="status"] #statuspanel-label[value*="TLS handshake"],
> #statuspanel[type="status"] #statuspanel-label[value*="FTP transaction"] {
>  display:none!important;
> }
> ```
>
> 17. Paste it in the userChrome.css file and Save it;
> 18. Close Firefox and Open it again, check if it worked.

Except this CSS did not achieve what I wanted to. Instead I wrote this CSS:

```
#statuspanel {
  display: none !important;
}

#statuspanel[type="overLink"] {
  display: block !important;
}
```

This hides everything except for link destinations.